# Best strategy to script a web journey in jmeter with too many json submits in requests

Tags: json, jmeter

I am in process of developing a Jmeter script for a web journey which has close to 30 transactions, I observe that there are like 20 requests(API calls) which are submitting heavy Json load(with lots of fields) and this Json structure varies significantly with key data( Account number), it doesn't look like corelating 100s of fields of each of these json requests is an efficient way of scripting. I did give a try to submit predefined Json files in the requests, but that way I would need at least 10 Json( 1 json per request) for each Account number and considering I am looking to test like 200 Account numbers, this also doesn't look like a reasonable approach. Can someone please suggest pointers to approach this ? Should I test APIs independently ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one strategy: your load test must represent real life application usage with 100% accuracy so I would go for separate APIs testing in 2 cases:

1. As the last resort if for some reason realistic workload is not possible
2. When one particular API is known to be a [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing) and you need to repeat the test focusing on one endpoint only

With regards to correlation there are some semi and fully automated correlation solutions like:

1. [Correlations Recorder Plugin for JMeter](https://github.com/Blazemeter/CorrelationRecorder) where you can specify the correlation rules prior to recording and all matching values will be automatically replaced with the respective extractors/variables
2. [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) which is capable of exporting recorded scripts in "SmartJMX" mode with automatic detection and correlation of dynamic elements
3. If the next request can be "constructed" from the previous response but with some transformation of the JSON structure you can amend the response and convert it to the required form using [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) - see [Apache Groovy - Parsing and Producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html) article for more information

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T, Agree with your comments 1 and 2.. However, your subsequent suggestion on the solutions:1 and 2 would not work, as the json structure for the requests vary significantly with data. Solution 3 would work, but imho may not be very efficient as I have a large number of requests with json structure varying with data. As a possible solution, I have suggested that we clone the data which we created the script with and ensure that all cloned data varies only in one known aspect, this would ensure that jsons are almost identical and script could be parameterized.